# Writing an instance controlled class

Tags: java

I want to make a class with a private constructor and a static factory method `of`. I want `of` to always return an existing instance of the class with the specified fields if such an instance has been created but has not been collected by the garbage collector.

I don't want to simply keep a `Set` of instances because that would prevent instances from being garbage collected. I thought about keeping a `WeakHashMap` or a `Set<WeakReference>`, but that would reduce `of` to a search, damaging performance if the size gets large.

The solution I thought of is something like this:

```
public final class Widget {

    private static final Map<Integer, Set<Reference<Widget>>> map = new HashMap<>();

    private final String string;
    private final int value;

    private Widget(String string, int value) {
        this.string = string;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Widget of(String string, int value) {
        if (string == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        int hash = 31 * string.hashCode() + value;
        Set<Reference<Widget>> set = map.get(hash);
        if (set == null) {
            set = new HashSet<>();
            map.put(hash, set);
        } else {
            for (Iterator<Reference<Widget>> i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Widget widget = i.next().get();
                if (widget == null)
                    i.remove();
                else if (widget.string.equals(string) && widget.value == value)
                    return widget;
            }
        }
        Widget widget = new Widget(string, value);
        set.add(new WeakReference<>(widget));
        return widget;
    }

    static void tidy() {
        for (Iterator<Set<Reference<Widget>>> i = map.values().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Set<Reference<Widget>> set = i.next();
            for (Iterator<Reference<Widget>> i2 = set.iterator(); i2.hasNext();)
                if (i2.next().get() == null)
                    i2.remove();
            if (set.isEmpty())
                i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that you'd have to call the `tidy()` method periodically, whereas I really want all tidying up to happen automatically.

Is there a simple or standard solution to this problem?

Comment: Why? What's the point? Creating a new object costs basically nothing. Much much less than what you're doing. And you're also putting more pressure on the GC, by keeping instances alive longer. Not to mention that your cache is more complex than needed: you're basically reimplementing what a HashMap does. You should jsut create a Key class, with a String, an int, and a proper hashCode and equals() method. Now of course, creating the key would be as costly as creating a new Widget in the first place.

Comment: @JBNizet Widget was just an example. In reality the instances take up a lot more memory. What I'm trying to do is read in large numbers of objects from a file. In the file, the objects are stored as raw fields (in this example a `String` and an `int`). If millions of matches occur when reading in the file I want only one object to be created. I'm trying to reduce the pressure on the GC.

Comment: So you basically want a cache. I would design a proper Key class containing the String and the int identifying a widget, and use an existing Cache implementation, like Guava's cache: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained. It's battle-tested, thread-safe, and is very flexible: weak refs if needed, time-based or size-based eviction policy, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet That looks like what I need. Thank you. I guess I was trying to avoid the need to create millions of identical key objects, but I think you're right that there's no reason to worry about that.

Comment: Wait, the cache is what allows you creating millions of identical objects. I would try without it first, because maybe you don't need it at all. If you use IO, the GC could have plenty of time doing its job while you're reading frolm the disk or network. And if you need it, the cach will make sure to return an already created widget based on its key, unless it has been evicted from the cache already.